# JavaScript: Module based Todo list needs simplification

Tags: javascript, oop

This is my todo list based on the Module Pattern, this is working fine and just want to know two things.

Is this code still can be simplified?
Once I added a list, if i refresh the page, then, these list are gone, but, my requirement is, these lists are deleted when i use 'Remove List'. How I can amend this? Any advise?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> TO-Do List In Javascript </title>
    <style>
    #message{
    left: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    }
    div#todo > div input {
    top:-39px;
    margin-left: 226px;

    position: relative;
    }
    div#todo > div > p {
        padding: 0px;
        width: 210px;

    }
    div#todo  div {
    top:0px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="itemin"><input type="text" id="txt1" name="text1"/><input type="button" id="bt1" value="Add List"/><input type="button" id="bt2" value="Remove List"/></div>
 <div id="todo">
 </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var Todo = Todo || {};

var element = document.getElementById("todo");
var elementChiCount="";

Todo.Item = (function(){

       function creatList(someInput) {

       elementChiCount = element.getElementsByTagName("div").length;

         var txtNode = document.createTextNode(someInput);
         var elemNode = document.createElement("p");
         elemNode.appendChild(txtNode);

         var elemCheckbox = document.createElement("input");

         elemCheckbox.setAttribute("id", 'check'+ elementChiCount);
         elemCheckbox.setAttribute("type", 'checkbox');

         var divElem = document.createElement("div");
          divElem.appendChild(elemNode);
          divElem.appendChild(elemCheckbox);

         divElem.setAttribute("id", "item"+elementChiCount);
         divElem.setAttribute("style", "border: 1px solid pink; width: 250px;padding-left:10px");
         element.appendChild(divElem);

     }
     function addList(txtInput) {
         creatList(txtInput);
     }
       function deleteList() {
         elementChiCount = element.getElementsByTagName("div").length;
         for (var i = 0; i < elementChiCount; i++) {

           var elementCurr = element.getElementsByTagName("div")[i];

         if(elementCurr.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked == true){
          var thisElem = elementCurr.parentNode;
         thisElem.removeChild(elementCurr);
         break;
         } else {
         }       }

     }

    return {
      add: addList,
      del: deleteList

    }
})();


    </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var actBtn = document.getElementById("bt1"); 
 var delBtn = document.getElementById("bt2"); 

 actBtn.onclick = function() {
 var txtVaue = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
 Todo.Item.add(txtVaue);
}

delBtn.onclick = function() {
 Todo.Item.del();
}
</script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For questions about simplifying working code, please post to [codereview.se] instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to your question regarding how to keep your lists until you want to remove them.

Why don't you take a look at [window.localstorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) to allow your lists to persist on refresh.

The following code uses the localStorage and JSON libraries.

The JSON library converts your listData json object into a string in order to store it (localStorage only stores strings), and then after retrieving that string, converting it back into a json object for you to use in your script.

```
// to save the list
var listDataAsString = JSON.stringify(listData);
localStorage.setItem('list_' + listId, listDataAsString);

// to get the list
var listDataAsString = localStorage.getItem('list_' + listId);
var listData = JSON.parse(listDataAsString);

// to remove the list
localStorage.removeItem('list_' + listId);
```

Personally I use the [localforage](https://mozilla.github.io/localForage/) library from mozilla, but then you need to look at promises or callbacks. This simplest is to use callbacks.

```
// to save the list
localforage.setItem('list_' + listId, listData, function (err, listData) {
    console.log('Saved list', listId, listData);
});

// to get the list
localforage.getItem('list_' + listId, function (err, listData) {
    console.log('Retrieved list', listId, listData);
});

// to remove the list
localforage.removeItem('list_' + listId, function (err, listData) {
    console.log('Removed list', listId, listData);
});
```

Even with the simple use case you seem to have, I would use localforage as it will handle choosing the best storage ***and*** any object to string conversion that may need to be carried out.